# Printing nested fields on Go objects

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand from the below code, how can I print only "species" and "width" key values.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Dimensions struct {
    Height int
    Width  int
}

type Bird struct {
    Species     string
    Description string
    Dimensions  Dimensions
}

func main() {
    birdJson := `{"species":"pigeon","description":"likes to perch on rocks", "dimensions":{"height":24,"width":10}}`
    var bird Bird
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(birdJson), &bird)
    fmt.Println(bird)
    // {pigeon likes to perch on rocks {24 10}}
}
```

The output I'm expecting is: pigeon and 10

Comment: To access fields of a struct instance you can use a [selector](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Selectors) expression: `fmt.Println(bird.Species, bird.Dimensions.Width)`. https://go.dev/play/p/SOZO5tUF-Mc

Comment: Why were you expecting that output?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here is printing the entire object when you should be printing the specific fields you're looking for. Instead, you should try this:

```
fmt.Println(bird.Species, bird.Dimensions.Width)
```

which will yield:

> pigeon 10

To make this a bit more readable, you can use `fmt.Printf` like so:

```
fmt.Printf("Species: %s, Width: %d\n", bird.Species, bird.Dimensions.Width)
```

which will yeild:

> Species: pigeon, Width: 10